# Php function to run mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create functions to run mysql queries

How would I do things like insert queries. I was thinking

```
function insert_query ($table,$cols,$values)
{
$sql="insert into $table ($cols) values ($values) "; ...etc
}
```

With the rest of the query code in the function. But how would I add multiple columns and values?

Should I make `$cols` and `$values` An array inside the function?

Comment: use mysqli_* or pdo statements..

Comment: ^Yeah! Use PDO - Prepared Statements! So you can execute the queries as and when you want!

Comment: I am starting to learn mysqli , so I will be using that in my function

Comment: pdo it's kind of unfriendly and that's why I use mysqli

Comment: @HellBaby With PHP's documentation and a bit of Google Search,  it becomes really easy! :)

Comment: Old ways are better for a `old` man. I started with mysql syntax and when I changed to mysqli was a pain in my ass(cause nothing was clear to me), worked with pdo also but didn't like it cause of the stupid syntax. I don't have any idea who composed that syntax but he/they need to be poked in face(my opinion so don't jump ...).

Comment: Never put a $variable directly into the SQL query unless you know 100% for sure that it's trustworthy. If it's a variable coming from a user then you're introducing an opportunity for a SQL injection attack. You should either escape the string or use prepared statements.

Comment: Just a note to saw mysqli does support prepared statements, as well as PDO. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just us arrays

```
function insert_query ($table,$cols,$values){
    $sql="insert into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") values (".implode("','", $values)."'') ";
}

insert_query('exampleTable', array('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'), array('a', 123, 'c') );
```

**The implode for the values requires a small sidenote:**
Strings always required being wrapped in quotes. Therefor I made the implode with single qoutes. The downside to this is that integets (like `123` in the example) also get wrapped.
This is not a big problem, but if you want you could replace the implode with a foreach that uses `is_numeric` to check wether it should be wrapped in quotes.

**IMPORTANT SECURITY NOTE:**
In this example I havent used proper seurity, like `escape_string()`, this has to be added! I've not added thos to keep the examples smaller

---

Another approach could be key/value-usage of an array:

```
function insert_query ($table,$data){
    $cols = array_keys($data);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $sql = "insert into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") values (".implode("','", $values)."'') ";
}
$info = array('column_1'=>'a', 'column_2'=>123, 'column_3'=>'c');
$info['example'] = 'Easy method to add more key/values';
insert_query('tableName', $info);
```

Comment: You are not escaping the values. This leaves this code open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I know, I did that to keep it simpler. One could add an array_map with a check to see if it is string-> add quotes, and anti--sqlinject it. I've added a note to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use functions similar to codeigniter functions.
Use arrays to store table name and columns or values

For example:

```
$data = array('hid' => $hcsdate,'start_date' => $sdate, 'end_date' => $edate, 'title' =>$title);
```

Here `$data` holds the column name and corresponding values.

And pass this `$data` to another functions for insert, update etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using. Pass field name and Value as Array key and value. $lsQry is an array of field name & value pair

```
function insert_record($table,$lsQry)
{
    $fields_str = implode(',',array_keys($lsQry));
    $data_str = implode("','",$lsQry);        
    $data_str = "'" . implode("','", $lsQry) . "'";         

    $lsQry = "INSERT INTO $table($fields_str) VALUES($data_str)";
    $rs = mysql_query($lsQry);

    if(isset($rs))
        return true;
    else
        return false;        
}
```

**Please Note**

For this function, do consider that function is getting an array of fields name and value pair. It is assumed that htmlentities() and addslashes() or any escaping functions are already applied while creating array from post/get values.

Comment: Well its all based on how developer would like to use. This code block just gives an idea and a solution. Doesn't claims to be all standardize.

Comment: This doesn't escape the values, leaving this open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of my Database Class.

```
public function insert($table,$values){               
                $fieldNames = "";
                $fieldValues = "";

                foreach($values as $key => $value){
                    $fieldNames .= "$key,";
                    $fieldValues .= "$value,";
                }
                $fieldNames = substr($fieldNames,0,-1);
                $fieldValues = substr($fieldValues,0,-1);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $table($fieldNames) VALUES ($fieldValues)";

                $this->newConnection();
                $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
                $this->closeConnection();
                return $result;
  }
```

Comment: Im wondering why you choose for a `foreach` and a `substr()`. Why not a simple implode? Native array-functions are faster that 'manual'loops

Comment: You are not escaping the $value leaving this open to SQL injection attacks. You also don't quote the $value within the SQL so this won't work with string values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the native array functions that's why I used the `foreach` and `substring`.

Comment: @steveayre I'm having a hard time figuring out how will I quote the values. Can you improve that code? Thanks.